# CasperJS scrolling content

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to aggregate some data from Facebook. I need CasperJS to load posts that are "older". I have found found the element that I need to click to load more content and wrote this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#pagelet_group_pager div div div a')[0].click();
```

which works fine in chrome's console but when do:

```
this.evaluate(function() {
            document.querySelectorAll('div#pagelet_group_pager div div div a')[0].click();
    });
```

or

```
this.click('div#pagelet_group_pager div div div a');
```

in the CasperJS script no new content loads.

any advice??

Thanks.